# Code first, many to many relation between table and view in .Net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I want to define many to many relations between Table and View as First code. In my case, I have two databases that one of them can't touch any of the tables, so I had to create a view from tables. another database I created for my application and I want to join tables and view to each other. Here I want to share the entity below:

Table:

```
public class Collection
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CollectionRole { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public ICollection<ActiveProductToCollection> ActiveProductToCollections { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
 public class ActiveProductView
    {
   
        public string Id { get; set; } = null!;

        public string? ProductName { get; set; }

        public string? ProductDescription { get; set; }

    

         public ICollection<ActiveProductToCollection> ActiveProductToCollections { get; set; }
    }
```

And Another table:

```
public class ActiveProductToCollection
{
     public string ActiveProductId { get; set; }
    public Guid CollectionId { get; set; }
    public Collection Collections { get; set; }
    public ActiveProductView ActiveProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Also OnModelCreating in my context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveProductToCollection>().HasKey(p => new
        {
            p.ActiveProductId,
            p.CollectionId
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveProductView>().HasNoKey();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveProductToCollection>()
        .HasOne(p => p.ActiveProduct)
        .WithMany(s => s.ActiveProductToCollections)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.ActiveProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveProductToCollection>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Collections)
        .WithMany(p => p.ActiveProductToCollections)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CollectionId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```